# Eclipse Insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, eclipse

I have reached a problem where java virtual machine simply does not have enough memory to compile. What should I do about this?

The jvm is run by eclipse and it is already part of the 64 bit server. I am running approx 600 lines of code in one class with dependency on a few other classes with data read and saved in text file.

The error report is shown below

---

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1048576 bytes for 
AllocateHeap

Possible reasons:
The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
Possible solutions:
Reduce memory load on the system
Increase physical memory or swap space
Check if swap backing store is full
Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
Decrease number of Java threads
Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
This output file may be truncated or incomplete.

Out of Memory Error (memory/allocation.inline.hpp:61), pid=25196, 
tid=0x0000000000006218

JRE version:  (8.0_144-b01) (build )
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode windows-
amd64 compressed oops)
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client 
versions of Windows
```

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

```
Current thread (0x00000000023a0800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" 
[_thread_in_vm, id=25112, stack(0x00000000021b0000,0x00000000022b0000)]

Stack: [0x00000000021b0000,0x00000000022b0000]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing stack bounds), id 
0xc0000005]

Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native 
code)
```

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

```
Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x00000000023a0800 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, 
id=25112, stack(0x00000000021b0000,0x00000000022b0000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
PSYoungGen      total 37888K, used 655K [0x00000000d6400000,             
0x00000000d8e00000, 0x0000000100000000)
eden space 32768K, 2% used     
[0x00000000d6400000,0x00000000d64a3d80,0x00000000d8400000)
from space 5120K, 0% used 
[0x00000000d8900000,0x00000000d8900000,0x00000000d8e00000)
to   space 5120K, 0% used 
[0x00000000d8400000,0x00000000d8400000,0x00000000d8900000)
ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 0K [0x0000000082c00000, 
0x0000000088000000, 0x00000000d6400000)
object space 86016K, 0% used 
[0x0000000082c00000,0x0000000082c00000,0x0000000088000000)
 Metaspace       used 746K, capacity 4480K, committed 4480K, reserved 
1056768K
class space    used 75K, capacity 384K, committed 384K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011860000,0x0000000011c50000] byte_map_base:     
0x000000001144a000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006bb9d850
Begin Bits: [0x00000000122f0000, 0x0000000014240000)
End Bits:   [0x0000000014240000, 0x0000000016190000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000630000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=328Kb max_used=328Kb free=245431Kb
bounds [0x00000000024a0000, 0x0000000002710000, 0x00000000114a0000]
total_blobs=58 nmethods=0 adapters=38    
compilation: enabled

Compilation events (0 events):
No events

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.310 loading class java/lang/Short
Event: 0.311 loading class java/lang/Short done
Event: 0.311 loading class java/lang/Integer
Event: 0.312 loading class java/lang/Integer done
Event: 0.312 loading class java/lang/Long
Event: 0.313 loading class java/lang/Long done
Event: 0.320 loading class java/lang/NullPointerException
Event: 0.320 loading class java/lang/NullPointerException done
Event: 0.320 loading class java/lang/ArithmeticException
Event: 0.320 loading class java/lang/ArithmeticException done
```

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

```
OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 14393 (10.0.14393.1198)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family     
6 model 78 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1,     
sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, 
tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 8204552k(3151664k free), swap 33370376k(6360k     
free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01) for windows-amd64 
JRE (1.8.0_144-b01), built on Jul 21 2017 21:57:33 by "java_re" with MS VC++     
10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sat Nov 04 21:20:44 2017
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Comment: what are the values of Xms-Xmx values in eclipse.ini, the file that's in eclipse home folder.

Comment: They are -Xms256m and -Xmx1024m

Comment: You have the problem running your application (started from within Eclipse) and Eclipse itself doesn't crash, right? If yes, you have to set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` in your run configuration as VM arguments.

Comment: So for instance I can change the xmx heap size to 2048m safely without affecting the application?